# What is the best way to deal with multiple else if statements to increase speed in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that is supposed to unhide certain columns, but only if other filters that relate to the columns are not in use. Because there are 4 other filters that it needs to check to see if they are in use (either 'true' or 'false'), there are 16 possibilities that the function needs to run through.

I've used *else if* statements to accomplish this and it does work, but it is incredibly slow. I was wondering if there is a more appropriate way to deal with all the possible options that is faster.

This is the code I currently have (sorry if I've shown too much, not sure how much I need to include):

```
function Unfilter(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var numCols = sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue(); //gets the number of columns to loop through
  var xRow = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue() + 16; //gets the target row to run the blank check on
  // check filter statuses 
  var nameShow = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue(); 
  var statusShow = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue(); 
  var dateShow = sheet.getRange(3,1).getValue();
  var evidenceShow = sheet.getRange(4,1).getValue();
  //loop through all target columns and unhide all columns that are not filtered
  for (var i=10; i<=numCols; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange(xRow,i).getValue() == "") {
    var catType = sheet.getRange(16,i).getValue();
      if (nameShow == true && statusShow == true && dateShow == true && evidenceShow == true) {
        sheet.showColumns(i)
      } else if (nameShow == false && statusShow == true && dateShow == true && evidenceShow == true) {
        if(catType !== "Name") {
          sheet.showColumns(i);
        }
      } else if (nameShow == false && statusShow == false && dateShow == true && evidenceShow == true){
          if (catType == "Date" || catType == "Evidence") {
           sheet.showColumns(i);
          }
      } else if (nameShow == false && statusShow == true && dateShow == false && evidenceShow == true) {
          if (catType == "Status" || catType == "Evidence") {
            sheet.showColumns(i);
          }
      } else if (nameShow == false && statusShow == true && dateShow == true & evidenceShow == false){
          if (catType == "Status"|| catType == "Date") {
            sheet.showColumns(i);
         }
      } else if (nameShow == false && statusShow == false && dateShow == false && evidenceShow == true){
          if (catType == "Evidence") {
            sheet.showColumns(i);
          }
      } else if (nameShow == false && statusShow == false && dateShow == true && evidenceShow == false){
          if (catType == "Date") {
            sheet.showColumns(i);
          }
      } 
      //...etc for all 9 remaining possibilities
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My experience with hiding and showing columns is that it's very  slow.  So it may not the logic that's the problem.

Comment: @MetaMan hmm yeah, I thought that it might be all the checks that it needed to do that was slowing it down and so was hoping there was a better method to achieve the same thing or at least clean up the code a little. If its just the showing columns that's slow though I guess I'm just stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you can't speed up `showColumns()` function you can significantly accelerate your script if you will use `getValue()` or `getValues()` as few as it possible. For example here you invoke these functions more than 7 times on the same sheet with static data. It's far from best practices:

[image]

You could use `getValues()` just once to get all data from the sheet and analyze the array instead. It would be much faster. `getValue()` / `getValues()` are quite slow and intentionally limited functions.

For example:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,10,10).getValues(); // get the array
var numCols      = data[0][2];
var xRow         = data[0][4] + 16;
var nameShow     = data[0][0];
var statusShow   = data[1][0];
var dateShow     = data[2][0];
var evidenceShow = data[3][0];
// etc
```

I think it will be about five seconds faster already.

And it will even more faster if you change `getRange(xRow,i).getValue()` to `data[xRow-1][i-1]` in the loop.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I'm very new to this so these best principles are very useful. The execution time went from 15 seconds down to 1!